# jQuery .on() performing differently than expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Using AJAX, I am populating a container with the id of `logos-page-main-content-wrapper` (assigned to a variable called `mainContent`) on a WordPress page with several levels of descendants; the important (images) descendants have the class `medallion-image`.

The following jQuery function performs differently than I expect:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var mainContent = $('#logos-page-main-content-wrapper');
    var medallionImage = $('.medallion-image');
    var combinedMarkImage = $('.combined-mark-image');
    var monogramImage = $('.monogram-image');
    var wordmarkImage = $('wordmark-image');

    mainContent.on('click', medallionImage,function(){

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'validateUser',
                security: ajax_object.ajax_nonce,
                current_post_id: ajax_object.current_post_id
            },
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data != true){
                    window.location = window.location.hostname + '/login';
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The idea is that when a user clicks on the image with the class of `medallion-image` they will be redirected to a login page if they aren't currently logged into WordPress. The AJAX call works properly, but the `.on()` function responds to a click on any descendant of `mainContent` instead of just clicks on the `medallion-image` images. As I understand it, this shouldn't be happening; only the `medallion-image` class should respond to clicks.

I've scoured the documentation for `.on` on the jQuery API site but haven't figured out why it's behaving this way. Any ideas?

Comment: [Read the manual](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It expects a **selector**, not a jQuery element.

Comment: So, `var medallionImage = '.medallion-image';`

Comment: The doco says pretty clearly that the second argument to `.on()` is supposed to be a string that is a selector, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Man, y'all had me excited thinking it was just a dumb mistake on my part (which it was), sadly `mainContent.on('click', '.medallion-image', function(){` performs the same way.

Comment: Why using `.on('click'...` and not `.click(function(){ ...` ?

Comment: Using `.click(function){` would work if the `.medallion-image`  `img` elements existed on the initial page load, but since they don't exist until after an AJAX call I need to use delegated events to get the same sort of functionality.

Comment: Interesting development: I develop on my localhost using MAMP and later push my changes to a dev-site that's on a live server. I pushed the function as follows: `mainContent.on('click','.medallion-image',function(){` changing the second argument from a jQuery object to a string containing a selector as pointed out by the above comments. The code works properly on the dev site, the clicks are only registered by the `medallion-image` class and nothing else. It still doesn't work properly on MAMP, so it might just be an issue with MAMP itself, though I cannot fathom what that would be.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the correct behaviour because jQuery will consider `.medallion-image` clicked even though you clicked on child elements. This works well because imagine if you have a table of content and you bind `.on` to the row. Instead building a bunch of child selectors of different elements in the row it triggers based on the fact that you interacted with the row. Here is the behaviour similar to the "issue" you're having:

https://jsfiddle.net/zLfqoj65/

A method to do it so it only executes the function on the parent and only the parent element is to do a check in your `.on` to ensure that this is the element you want with:

```
$('.outer').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('outer')) {
    // Execute code.
  }
});
```

This will check to see if this element you clicked on has the exact class you want. Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zLfqoj65/2/

Comment: Problem is that the `.medallion-image` images don't have child elements, they ARE the children (more accurately descendants) of `#logos-page-main-content-wrapper`. The ancestors of the `medallion-image` images (which are themselves descendants of `#logos-page-main-content-wrapper`) also register the click events, including every ancestor of `medallion-image` until `#logos-page-main-content-wrapper`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh I see, I mis-read your queston. In that case does this work: mainContent.find('.medallion-image').on('click', function() {});

Comment: That does the same thing, unfortunately. I should clarify too: it's not just ancestors of  the `.medallion-image`, but every descendent of `#logos-page-main-content-wrapper`. I did get it working outside of my localhost though, see above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do prevent capturing the click on mainContent using CSS pointer-events property as:

```
pointer-events: none
```

and in the medallion-image turn it back on using:

```
pointer-events: auto
```